# How to create a link that lets the user Reset Their Password when Signed In with Devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

With devise, if you navigate to the reset your password link, it only shows the view if you are signed in.

For signed in users, I would like to provide them with a link to "reset their password" - Anyone know if this is possible, how?

Thanks

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Reset password is generally reserved for those who can't sign in. If you're already signed in, the solution would just be to change your password.

Answer (score 0):

If you run `rake routes` you'll see 2 relevant paths: `edit_user_password` and `edit_user_registration`.

`edit_user_password` is for users who would like to reset their password, but are not signed in, via a reset token.

`edit_user_registration` is used to edit the current user's information, including **resetting his or her password**, when the user is signed in. If you'd like to customize this further, ensure that you've generated the devise views: `rails generate devise:views`, see "Configuring views" [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise)). The corresponding view in this case is `devise/registrations/edit.html.erb`.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= link_to "Sign up", new_user_registration_path %>
<%= link_to "Sign in", new_user_session_path %>
<%= link_to "Sign out", destroy_user_session_path %>
<%= link_to "Edit settings", edit_user_password %>
```